# How to know what ctrl-z will do in windows explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, undo

In earlier windows versions, I could open windows explorer and use the menu bar to mouse-over on "undo", and the status bar would show some information about which file(s) will be involved. I seem to remember some trick about pressing shift before the mouse-over, to know more information.

Now, in windows 10, I see that right-click shows "undo X" where X is an operation like copy or move, but I am not able to see which file(s) were copied or moved.

How to know which file(s) will be "un-copied" or "un-moved" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution for one-file operations only:

Above the Home tab, select the small down-pointing arrow to display the
*Customize Quick Access Toolbar*, and select *Undo* from the drop-down list.

After a one-file operation, hovering over the added Undo icon will show
the operation and the name of the file.
Unfortunately, for multi-file operations the names are not shown.

Comment: +1 , I had already tried this with and without shift, but it was showing "undo copy", without any names ; Your answer implies that I have copied multiple files.